# Have ribbon use a custom SSLContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

I have a spring boot app with zuul and ribbon (no eureka) and I need to forward all traffic over https with mutual tls. The keystore and password are all automatically generated by an internal framework. At the end I end up with an SSLContext spring bean which I would like ribbon to use when forwarding zuul requests. Now my question is how do I force ribbon to use my `SSLContext`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You need to register your own SSLSocketFactory and initialize it with your own SSLContext. Then set the ribbon property `ribbon.CustomSSLSocketFactoryClassName: full-path-to-your-CustomSslSocketFactory`

```
public class CustomSslSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    public CustomSslSocketFactory() throws Exception {
        super(SSLContextConfig.createSSLContext());
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @bjoern, would you mind sharing your application.properties or application.yml to establish how did you configure ribbon, please? I have used your method, without any luck. I have to add that I am attempting mutual authentication via SSL